# Parsing HTML Tags from JSON response using AFNetworking

Tags: html, ios, json, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to get JSON response and populate my UITableView based on it. However, i'm getting HTML tags such as `<a href='link'>` in some of the JSON responses. How can i remove them and get proper formatting while populating my tableview cells?

Below is the code for reloading data in tableview using AFNetworking from JSON response -

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxx.com/api.php?req=all"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation      JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse   *response, id responseObject) {


    self.jobsArrayFromAFNetworking = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"all"]mutableCopy];

    [spinner stopAnimating];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"JSON RESULT %@",responseObject);

  }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id    responseObject){

    NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@, %@",error,error.userInfo);
   }];

  [operation start];

 }
```

Comment: I'm not clear: are you wanting to strip HTML tags from the data, so that they aren't rendered directly into your table view cells?

Comment: I want html tags to appear in right way. Indirectly, i want to parse those html tags everywhere from JSON response.

Comment: So you want to render the HTML tags, so that the formatting is displayed in your table view cells?

Comment: YES. Not even in tableView cells, but wherever i want them to be shown.

Comment: To show the HTML formatting, you'd need to update your cells to contain `UIWebView`s or use some third party HTML rendering text view. It has nothing to do with AFNetworking or JSON, really. You're already getting the right response data and strings, you just have to choose the appropriate view components with which to render them later on.

Comment: An example would help a lot. Any?

Answer (score 0):

You could of course roll your own decoder, but there's a great implementation in MWFeedParser to strip html tags and do some very useful things with links:

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString%2BHTML.m

With this category, you can simply call `stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText` on your strings before using them in your table.

Comment: I saw this. But how should i get this implemented with AFNetworking? This changes the entire code i have written.

Comment: I just read your comments that clarify what you want to do.  First of all, I think the choice of implementing NSString parsing at the AFNetworking-level is probably a bad design.  That being said, you can easily subclass your AFHTTPClient or your json response operation to implement this.  Then when you want to display the links in labels, use something like: https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel